# calculate means with phantom zeros using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate summary statistics for tree volume data from a standard forest "cruise."  Basically, we measure tree volumes in several randomly located circular plots within a spatially delineated area of the forest called a "stand."  I want to provide the summary statistics grouped by species. Some tree species are rare in the stand and only occur in a few plots.  We don't record any data for those species in the plots they don't occur in, but technically we have observed 0 volume for those species in the plots in which they don't occur.  Therefore the mean is appropriately calculated as the sum of the volume divided by the total number of plots in the cruise, but when using `dplyr::summarize()`, means are calculated as the sum of volumes divided by the number of plots in which a tree species occurs.  For example:

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr)

#For Reproducibility#
set.seed(63)

#Creating Fake Data#
plots<-c(1:25)
species<-c("PSME", "PSME", "PSME", "TSHE", "PSME", "PSME",  "PSME", "THPL", "PIMO3", "ACMA3")
trees<-data.frame(plot_id=rep(plots,5), species=sample(species, 125, replace=TRUE), vol=rnorm(125, 3250, 30)) %>% 
  arrange(plot_id)

#Calculating Mean volume by species
trees %>% group_by(species) %>% summarize(across(.cols=2,~mean(.x)))
```

Is there an option I can pass to `dplyr::summarize()` to get it calculate the mean as the sum of the volume for a given species divide by the total number of plots in a cruise?  Below is my somewhat ugly workaround to achieve my desired outcome.

```
##Continued from previous chunk of code##

#create a sparse matrix using pivot_wider()#
trees_sparse<-trees %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = plot_id, names_from=species, values_from = vol, values_fn=sum)

#Change NAs to Zeros#
trees_sparse[is.na(trees_sparse)]<-0

#Convert back to long format retaining zeros#
trees_zeros<-trees_sparse %>% pivot_longer(cols = -1, names_to = "Species", values_to = "Volume")

#Desired summary statistics#
trees_zeros %>%  group_by(Species) %>%  summarize(across(.cols=2, ~mean(.x)))
```

Comment: Use `tidyr::complete` to fill in zeroes (replacing your second block) for the stands where the species doesn't appear. Alternatively, you could calculate the sum inside summarize and the total number of plots separately, and divide after the fact.

Comment: Thanks, Calum! That's exactly the solution I was after.  If you want reputation credit, post it as an answer and I'll accept and upvote it.

Comment: I realized `complete` isn't a perfect fit because you also want to aggregate the volume of each species in each plot (missed your `values_fn = sum`). But i included it anyway just in case. thanks for providing reproducible data and output - makes it much easier to understand and check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tidyr::complete` to fill in missing species-plot combinations, but you need to additionally re-aggregate to the plot-species level. You could also avoid this in this case by calculating the numerator and denominator separately.

```r
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr)

set.seed(63)

plots <- c(1:25)
species <- c("PSME", "PSME", "PSME", "TSHE", "PSME", "PSME", "PSME", "THPL", "PIMO3", "ACMA3")
trees <- data.frame(
  plot_id = rep(plots, 5),
  species = sample(species, 125, replace = TRUE),
  vol = rnorm(125, 3250, 30)
) %>%
  arrange(plot_id)

# This is a tidyr way to do your second block:
trees %>%
  complete(plot_id, species, fill = list(vol = 0)) %>%
  group_by(plot_id, species) %>%
  summarise(plot_vol = sum(vol)) %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarise(avg_vol = mean(plot_vol))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   species avg_vol
#>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 ACMA3      908.
#> 2 PIMO3      780.
#> 3 PSME     11550.
#> 4 THPL      1041.
#> 5 TSHE      1957.

# Or you could separately calculate the sum and the denominator:
trees %>%
  group_by(species, n_plots = n_distinct(plot_id)) %>%
  summarize(sum_vol = sum(vol)) %>%
  mutate(mean_vol = sum_vol / n_plots)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#> # Groups:   species [5]
#>   species n_plots sum_vol mean_vol
#>   <chr>     <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 ACMA3        25  22695.     908.
#> 2 PIMO3        25  19501.     780.
#> 3 PSME         25 288743.   11550.
#> 4 THPL         25  26030.    1041.
#> 5 TSHE         25  48935.    1957.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>